# How to get Apache CLI to handle double-dash?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

I've looked at the docs but can't see how to get the Apache Commons CLI to handle the double-hyphen "option" that normally terminates option processing.

Consider the following command-line which has an "-opt" option which can take an optional argument that is not specified:

```
MyProgram -opt -- param1 param2
```

I want the option to end up with no arguments in this case, but Apache returns "--" as an argument.  If the option allowed for more than one argument, then some or all of the parameters would get returned as arguments.

Here is sample code illustrating the issue:

```
package com.lifetouch.commons.cli;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;

public class DoubleHyphen {
  private static Options options = new Options();

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // One required option with an optional argument:
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    OptionBuilder builder = OptionBuilder.isRequired(true).
            withDescription("one optional arg").
            withArgName("optArg").hasOptionalArgs(1);
    options.addOption(builder.create("opt"));

    // Illustrate the issue:
    doCliTest(new String[] { "-opt"} );
    doCliTest(new String[] { "-opt", "optArg", "param"} );
    doCliTest(new String[] { "-opt", "--", "param"} );
    // What I want is for the double-dash to terminate option processing.
    // Note that if "opt" used hasOptionalArgs(2) then "param" would be a second
    // argument to that option (rather than an application parameter).
  }

  private static void doCliTest(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("\nTEST CASE -- command line items: " + Arrays.toString(args));

    // Parse the command line:
    CommandLine cmdline = null;
    try {
        CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
        cmdline = parser.parse(options, args); // using stopAtNonOption does not help
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.err.println("Command line parse error: " + ex);
        return;
    }

    // Observe the results for the option and argument:
    String optArgs[] = cmdline.getOptionValues("opt");
    if (null == optArgs) {
        System.out.println("No args specified for opt");
    } else {
        System.out.println(optArgs.length + " arg(s) for -opt option: " +
                Arrays.toString(optArgs));
    }

    // Observe the results for the command-line parameters:
    String tmp = Arrays.toString(cmdline.getArgList().toArray());
    System.out.println(cmdline.getArgList().size() +
            " command-line parameter(s): " + tmp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest Apache Commons CLI **1.2** version?

Comment: Then the `PosixParser` below should work. See [PosixParser.java](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/commons-cli/commons-cli-1.2/org/apache/commons/cli/PosixParser.java.html) sourcecode: it does deal with `--` (see `private void processNonOptionToken(String value, boolean stopAtNonOption)` at line 182).

Comment: Neither the GnuParser nor the PosixParser handle the -- option properly, particularly when it appears where an optional argument might be. The command line "-a -- -b" puts the -- as an argument to the -a option, and -b is always treated like an option (not a parameter). This is regardess of the stopAtNonOption setting. My test code above can easily illustrate this.

Comment: Can you use `OptionBuilder.withValueSeparator()` in order to prevent the issue? This way the optional argument must be separated from the option by a `=` and the parser won't get confused. You can also specify a custom character with with `OptionBuilder.ValueSeparator(char sep)` if the equals sign is not appropriate. I know this is not exactly what you wanted to achieve, but it might be a viable workaround.

Comment: This would drastically change the definition of options and their parameters, and break the contract presented to my users. Space-delimited options are currently in use. That may be an approach that might work for others, though.

Comment: Since CLI 1.2 is missing the options-terminator `--`, let me provide you with an alternative. You could maintain the definition of options and their parameters and change your command line intepreting library, while keeping the contract presented to your users intact, assuming you can live **without** _options with optional args_ (it doesn't support them). [JArgs](http://jargs.sourceforge.net) has a "_GNU-compatible command-line options parser_" that "_allows options with associated values (-d 2, --debug 2, --debug=2). Option processing can be explicitly terminated by the argument `--`_"

Comment: Package also comes with a ready to use [class](https://github.com/purcell/jargs/blob/master/src/jargs/gnu/CmdLineParser.java) for testing its capabilities.
If you want to give it a try, you can download it from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jargs/files/jargs/1.0/).
Also, its [API](http://jargs.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.html) looks very straightforward to use.

Answer (score 6):

In order to handle the special token `--` as an option terminator, you must use the POSIX parser.

Use

```
CommandLineParser parser = new PosixParser();
```

instead of

```
CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();
```

Comment: As noted in my OP comments (above), simply switching to the PosixParser doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with both a `true` and a `false` `stopAtNonOption` option? If that doesn't help, then Apache Commons CLI is not compliant with [POSIX Conventions for Command Line Arguments](http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/essential/attributes/_posix.html) and I'll file in a bug report myself

Comment: Yes. The stopAtNonOption value doesn't matter, for the GnuParser or the PosixParser. My test program above can easily demonstrate this. Observe the results for the third test case never change. To reinforce the point, add a test case for "-opt -- -opt2".

Comment: Note also that changing stopAtNonOption to true really changes how a command line like this is handled: "-opt1 param1 arg1 -opt2 arg2 arg3". I'm not looking to drastically change the option parsing semantics, I just want to handle the -- correctly.

Comment: I just found this bug listed on _Apache Commons CLI_'s [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CLI-161): the bug gets fixed in versions 1.3 and 2.X, which have not been packaged as a release yet. However, you can find a [Commons CLI 1.3 snapshot](http://www.mygrid.org.uk/maven/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-cli/1.3-20100616.143343/) [here](http://www.mygrid.org.uk/maven/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-cli/1.3-20100616.143343/commons-cli-1.3-20100616.143343.jar)

Comment: That fix was made in May 2009 (for 1.3). Based on the notes, the fix is only for the GnuParser, and may not work in combination with optional arguments.

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty because Unai Vivi really worked at this, and I appreciate that effort. But I did not accept the answer because I still don't have a solution to make the Apache Commons CLI 1.2 handle double-dash properly.

Comment: @MikeC Thank you, I wish I could've helped more. Take care

Comment: In newer versions, the `PosixParser` has been **deprecated**.